# Can you please help me in Oracle for writing the table contents in to a file using UTL functions

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, ora-06512

While writing the SQL procedure for creating a CSV file from the contents of the table,
I am stuck at the error below:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 488
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "DSI_DPIPE.BUSSHOURS", line 28
ORA-06512: at "DSI_DPIPE.BUSSHOURS", line 55
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

First line is:

```
file_http UTL_FILE.file_type;
```

Same error is coming even i am using the statement:

```
file_http sys.UTL_FILE.file_type;
```

Thanks for your valuable solution in advance.

Comment: Can you describle your environment?  i.e. what operation system, what version of Oracle?

Comment: Should have said "describe" (mind you, describble would be great word...)

Comment: more code, please. What's in line 28?

Answer (score 2):

Has the oracle user access privileges for writing in the directory that you want to put the file?

**EDIT:** If you're in a Unix enviroment, you should manually login as the oracle user, go to the path that you're trying to create the file and use the command "touch" to create a file. If you can't create a file in this manner, you know that the problem is about "access privileges" in the operating sistem, else the problem is in ORACLE. (will reduce the search in 50% ;D )

**EDIT 2:**
If UTL_FILE_DIR = * then database permissions are disable and all files and directories are accessible to all user. But I think this applies only in a database level, so the operating system has also something to say. If the oracle user don't have a write access to some directory, then the users of the database can't adquire this right, no matter that UTL_FILE_DIR says.

Comment: I have UTL_FILE_DIR = * there fore no problem for that

Comment: can u pls extend u r time to suggest me one more way of solving this error

Answer (score 2):

Use the CREATE DIRECTORY feature instead of UTL_FILE_DIR for directory access verification.

UTL_FILE_DIR = * is dangerous because is allows database users that have access to the utl_file package to read/write files on the database server with the permissions of the user oracle (datafiles,init.ora, listener.ora etc.).

Do you have the right permissions to write/read to the directory. User oracle on the server needs read/write permission.

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory path is correct and you have the right permissions set (i.e. Oracle is allowed by the operating system to write to that location).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand that comment, can you rephrase it?

Comment: I have UTL_FILE_DIR = * there fore no problem from permissions set

Comment: UTL_FILE_DIR = * is a setting inside oracle.  It removes restrictions on what directories can be written to.  It makes no difference if the operating system (unix in your case) is preventing Oracle from writing to that location.

Comment: Try logging in to unix using the same operating system user account as the oracle database is using, and writing a file to that location.